# Blender 2.8 The object disappears if I change its color in edit mode

Tags: modeling

This is my object
[image]

I go in edit mode and on faces. I pick one face, go to materials, new material and change the color and get this to make the face disappear
[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is?
Thank you!

Comment: Please share the scene, where this happens. You can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for sharing your files.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=96DJy9zS" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/96DJy9zS/)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce your problem. All seem to be fine here. I'm using Blender version 2.83.5.

Comment: I use that version too, but it happens to me with every blender 2.8, 2.81, 2.82. Older versions 2.79 work normally.

Comment: Are you able to make a video recording of the steps you are doing insode Blender and post it here or on youtube?
You can use the free OBS for video recordings: https://obsproject.com/

Comment: Here is video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXrIxUY_21A

Comment: Thank you. Interesting. I still can't reproduce it, even when I follow your steps.
- What operating system are you using? Windows 10 or other?
- Are you sure you've the latest graphic drivers installed?

The only way I see is to uninstall and completely delete Blender and its user data. Then reinstall it and see if the issue still happen.

Comment: My operating system is windows 7. I'll do that and let you know if it's working well. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I solved the problem. I update a graphics drivers, and now it works normally. Thank you!